# Cannot execute any statement in express route except last

Tags: node.js, express

I have set up an express route, which is expected to serve an HTML file, which is this:

```
app.use('/',express.static("../first-app/dist"));
var filepath=path.join(__dirname,"..","first-app","dist","index.html");
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

        console.log("hello");
        console.log("hello");
        res.sendFile(filepath);

});
```

When '/' route is hit, the file is served correctly but none of the statement above `res.sendFile` is being executed. This is little bit strange because the statements are expected to execute in sequence. No matter what I write above the last line, nothing will execute.

Please help me to find the problem in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Theres nothing above the last line in your code. What are you trying to execute

Comment: console.log() are above the last line. By last line, I mean res.sendFile

Comment: Its your `static` middleware who is serving the file. Once done, no more routes are executed

Comment: I think you should look at the code and the question again. I don't have anymore routes, but all statements should execute inside this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response/file is getting sent, if these are all your routes and if you don't see the output from `console.log("hello");`, then the only possible answer is that this route:

```
app.use('/',express.static("../first-app/dist"));
```

is what is sending the file.  From your code, it looks like this will be the case because `index.html` is inside the `../first-app/dist` and if `express.static()` gets a request for `/`, then it looks for `index.html` in the target directory.  If it finds it, then it sends it and routing does not continue any further.

So, you have a couple possible solutions.

1. Move `index.html` somewhere else so `express.static()` doesn't find it and then change where you build `filepath` from to the new location of `index.html`.
2. Add an option to `express.static("../first-app/dist", {index: false}) to tell it not to look for`index.html`if the path is`/`.  You can see that option [documented here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static).
3. Move the `app.get('/', ...)` route before the `express.static()` route so it gets the request first.

Comment: You're a genius. I always wonder why such things don't come to my mind, how long you've been doing node?

Comment: @SatishTyagi - I've been using Express for a couple of years.  But also answering Express questions here and `express.static()` seems to be frequently misunderstood so there are lots of questions involving it.  Anyway, glad to be able to help.